# Run multiple instance of 1 python script and update its variables in real time

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

Hello I want to update a variable in real time when I run multiple instance of the same python script. Is it possible?
I am using pycharm and allow its multiple instance.

First Instance

```
print("Press X to print n")
n = input("Enter Number:")

if n == X:
   print(n)
else:
   print("Input Success")

Input is 5
Output should be "Input Success"
```

Second Instance

```
print("Press X to print n")
n = input("Enter Number:")

if n == X:
   print(n)
else:
   print("Input Success")

Input is X
Output should be 5
```

Im sorry I dont have any idea how this works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: To be clear, do you want to access the same variable value in both the python scripts?

Comment: @ZackVT Yes. If possible

Comment: Why not just combine them into 1 script?

Comment: @MattDMo This is only one python script which I run twice.

Comment: So write the shared data to disk and read the file when you need it. No need to muck about with multithreading and such.